# Java equivalent to unencode function in javascript to parse escaped unicode

Tags: java, json, escaping

I've trouble parsing tweets which are represented as escaped unicode some found to be foreign language strings
e.g `\u064a\u0633\u0639\u062f\u0646\u064a`

Answer (score 1):

Using `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils`.

```
String s="\\u0048\\u0065\\u006C\\u006C\\u006F";
System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(s));
```

P.S. Oops, I didn't refresh this page before I post the answer, the comments above conveys the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `str = org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str);`

from apache commons

check http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html